# href attribute in Jquery not being pulled correctly

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code to fade in the clicked tab but it keeps fading in the same tab regardless of which list item i click on:

```
$('#productinfowrap .tab:first').show();    
    $('#subselect li').click(function() {
        var thisTop = $(this).position().top;
        $('#subselect li').removeClass('current');
        var li = (this);
        $('.pointer').animate( {'top': thisTop}, function() { 
            $(li).addClass('current');
        });
        var id = $("#subselect li a").attr('href');
        $("#productinfowrap > div").fadeOut(500).hide();        
        $(id).fadeIn();
        return false;
    });
```

and the HTML

```
<ul id="subselect">
            <li class=""><a href="#overview">Overview</a><span class="pointer" style="top: 225px;"></span></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#applications">Applications</a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="#technical">Technical</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Other than the correct tab fading in, it all works perfectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line to:

```
var id = $(this).find("a").attr('href');
```

Comment: @Exe 16 minutes?? It's ages in SO time lines.. :-P

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(id).fadeIn();` why not just try `$(this).fadeIn();`

Comment: Thanks for your input duncan...i went with Shadow Wizrds response.